# How to make multiple invocations of same function work with Mockito.doReturn?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am performing unit tests on a service class (CompanyService) for which I mock 2 repository classes (CompanyEntityRepo and CompanyUserEntityRepo). The method I am testing in the service class recursively runs the same method on CompanyEntityRepo repository class.

When I call Mockito.mockingDetails(companyRepo).getInvocations(), I can't find any invocations on the CompanyEntityRepo class even though I added multiple ones for companyRepo.findByParentCompanyEntity() method.

invocations_1 has values in it (Working correctly).
invocations_2 has no values even though it is supposed to have been invoked 12 times.

This is for testing CompanyService class's getCompaniesAssignedToUser method which returns all companies the user has access to.

### CompanyServiceTest.java

```java
package unit.com.service;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockingDetails;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.invocation.Invocation;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import com.database.CompanyEntity;
import com.database.CompanyEntityRepo;
import com.database.CompanyUserEntity;
import com.database.CompanyUserEntityRepo;
import com.database.UserEntity;
import com.dto.CompanyDto;
import com.service.CompanyService;
import com.service.CompanyServiceImpl;
import com.cosium.spring.data.jpa.entity.graph.domain.EntityGraphs;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CompanyServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private CompanyEntityRepo companyRepo;

    @Mock
    private CompanyUserEntityRepo companyUserRepo;


    @Test
    // User assigned to BU1
    public void getComapniesAssignedToUser_WhenUserAssignedToTopLevel() throws Exception {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // Define return entities for companyUserRepo.findByUserEntity

        List<CompanyUserEntity> assignedBUs= new ArrayList<CompanyUserEntity>();

        UserEntity u = new UserEntity();    u.setId(1);
        CompanyEntity bu = new CompanyEntity(); bu.setId(1);

        CompanyUserEntity assignedBu = new CompanyUserEntity();
        assignedBu.setId(1);
        assignedBu.setUserEntity(u);
        assignedBu.setCompanyEntity(bu);

        assignedBUs.add(assignedBu);

        Mockito.doReturn(assignedBUs).when(companyUserRepo).findByUserEntity(
            u, EntityGraphs.named("business-unit-user-entity-graph-BUSINESS-UNIT")
        );

        // Define return entities for companyRepo.findByParentCompanyEntity
        // Because multiple companyRepo.findByParentCompanyEntity invocations are made, the output for each invocation has to be defined. For this all List<CompanyEntity> objects which would be returned need to be created.

        CompanyEntity bu1 = new CompanyEntity();    bu1.setId(1);   //bu1.setName("BU 1");
        CompanyEntity bu2 = new CompanyEntity();    bu2.setId(2);   //bu1.setName("BU 2");
        CompanyEntity bu3 = new CompanyEntity();    bu3.setId(3);   //bu1.setName("BU 3");
        CompanyEntity bu4 = new CompanyEntity();    bu4.setId(4);   //bu1.setName("BU 4");
        CompanyEntity bu5 = new CompanyEntity();    bu5.setId(5);   //bu1.setName("BU 5");
        CompanyEntity bu6 = new CompanyEntity();    bu6.setId(6);   //bu1.setName("BU 6");
        CompanyEntity bu7 = new CompanyEntity();    bu7.setId(7);   //bu1.setName("BU 7");
        CompanyEntity bu8 = new CompanyEntity();    bu8.setId(8);   //bu1.setName("BU 8");
        CompanyEntity bu9 = new CompanyEntity();    bu9.setId(9);   //bu1.setName("BU 9");
        CompanyEntity bu10 = new CompanyEntity();   bu10.setId(10); //bu1.setName("BU 10");
        CompanyEntity bu11 = new CompanyEntity();   bu11.setId(11); //bu1.setName("BU 11");
        CompanyEntity bu12 = new CompanyEntity();   bu12.setId(12); //bu1.setName("BU 12");

        List<CompanyEntity> subUnits_1 = new ArrayList<CompanyEntity>();    subUnits_1.add(bu2); subUnits_1.add(bu3); subUnits_1.add(bu4);
        List<CompanyEntity> subUnits_2 = new ArrayList<CompanyEntity>();    subUnits_2.add(bu5); subUnits_2.add(bu6);
        List<CompanyEntity> subUnits_3 = new ArrayList<CompanyEntity>();    subUnits_3.add(bu7); subUnits_3.add(bu8);
        List<CompanyEntity> subUnits_4 = new ArrayList<CompanyEntity>();
        List<CompanyEntity> subUnits_5 = new ArrayList<CompanyEntity>();    subUnits_5.add(bu9); subUnits_5.add(bu10);
        List<CompanyEntity> subUnits_6 = new ArrayList<CompanyEntity>();    subUnits_6.add(bu11); subUnits_6.add(bu12);
        List<CompanyEntity> subUnits_7 = new ArrayList<CompanyEntity>();
        List<CompanyEntity> subUnits_8 = new ArrayList<CompanyEntity>();
        List<CompanyEntity> subUnits_9 = new ArrayList<CompanyEntity>();
        List<CompanyEntity> subUnits_10 = new ArrayList<CompanyEntity>();
        List<CompanyEntity> subUnits_11 = new ArrayList<CompanyEntity>();
        List<CompanyEntity> subUnits_12 = new ArrayList<CompanyEntity>();

        Mockito.doReturn(subUnits_1).when(companyRepo).findByParentCompanyEntity(bu1, null);
        Mockito.doReturn(subUnits_2).when(companyRepo).findByParentCompanyEntity(bu2, null);
        Mockito.doReturn(subUnits_3).when(companyRepo).findByParentCompanyEntity(bu3, null);
        Mockito.doReturn(subUnits_4).when(companyRepo).findByParentCompanyEntity(bu4, null);
        Mockito.doReturn(subUnits_5).when(companyRepo).findByParentCompanyEntity(bu5, null);
        Mockito.doReturn(subUnits_6).when(companyRepo).findByParentCompanyEntity(bu6, null);
        Mockito.doReturn(subUnits_7).when(companyRepo).findByParentCompanyEntity(bu7, null);
        Mockito.doReturn(subUnits_8).when(companyRepo).findByParentCompanyEntity(bu8, null);
        Mockito.doReturn(subUnits_9).when(companyRepo).findByParentCompanyEntity(bu9, null);
        Mockito.doReturn(subUnits_10).when(companyRepo).findByParentCompanyEntity(bu10, null);
        Mockito.doReturn(subUnits_11).when(companyRepo).findByParentCompanyEntity(bu11, null);
        Mockito.doReturn(subUnits_12).when(companyRepo).findByParentCompanyEntity(bu12, null);


        // Prepare the output expected

        List<CompanyDto> expectedOutput = new ArrayList<CompanyDto>();

        CompanyDto _bu1 = new CompanyDto(); _bu1.setId(1);  _bu1.setName("BU 1");
        CompanyDto _bu2 = new CompanyDto(); _bu2.setId(2);  _bu2.setName("BU 2");
        CompanyDto _bu3 = new CompanyDto(); _bu3.setId(3);  _bu3.setName("BU 3");
        CompanyDto _bu4 = new CompanyDto(); _bu4.setId(4);  _bu4.setName("BU 4");
        CompanyDto _bu5 = new CompanyDto(); _bu5.setId(5);  _bu5.setName("BU 5");
        CompanyDto _bu6 = new CompanyDto(); _bu6.setId(6);  _bu6.setName("BU 6");
        CompanyDto _bu7 = new CompanyDto(); _bu7.setId(7);  _bu7.setName("BU 7");
        CompanyDto _bu8 = new CompanyDto(); _bu8.setId(8);  _bu8.setName("BU 8");
        CompanyDto _bu9 = new CompanyDto(); _bu9.setId(9);  _bu9.setName("BU 9");
        CompanyDto _bu10 = new CompanyDto();    _bu10.setId(10);    _bu10.setName("BU 10");
        CompanyDto _bu11 = new CompanyDto();    _bu11.setId(11);    _bu11.setName("BU 11");
        CompanyDto _bu12 = new CompanyDto();    _bu12.setId(12);    _bu12.setName("BU 12");

        List<CompanyDto> _subUnits_5 = new ArrayList<CompanyDto>(); _subUnits_5.add(_bu9);  _subUnits_5.add(_bu10);
        _bu5.setSubUnits(_subUnits_5);
        List<CompanyDto> _subUnits_6 = new ArrayList<CompanyDto>(); _subUnits_6.add(_bu11); _subUnits_6.add(_bu12);
        _bu6.setSubUnits(_subUnits_6);
        List<CompanyDto> _subUnits_2 = new ArrayList<CompanyDto>(); _subUnits_2.add(_bu5);  _subUnits_2.add(_bu6);
        _bu2.setSubUnits(_subUnits_2);
        List<CompanyDto> _subUnits_3 = new ArrayList<CompanyDto>(); _subUnits_3.add(_bu7);  _subUnits_3.add(_bu8);
        _bu3.setSubUnits(_subUnits_3);
        List<CompanyDto> _subUnits_1 = new ArrayList<CompanyDto>(); _subUnits_1.add(_bu2);  _subUnits_1.add(_bu3);  _subUnits_1.add(_bu4);

        expectedOutput.add(_bu1);

        // Perform the test

        CompanyService companieservice = new CompanyServiceImpl(companyRepo, companyUserRepo);
        List<CompanyDto> output = companieservice.getCompaniesAssignedToUser(new Integer(1));

        Collection<Invocation> invocations_1 = Mockito.mockingDetails(companyUserRepo).getInvocations();
        Collection<Invocation> invocations_2 = Mockito.mockingDetails(companyRepo).getInvocations();

        assertEquals(output, expectedOutput);
    }

}
```

### CompanyServiceImpl.java

```java
package com.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.database.CompanyEntity;
import com.database.CompanyEntityRepo;
import com.database.CompanyUserEntity;
import com.database.CompanyUserEntityRepo;
import com.database.UserEntity;
import com.dto.CompanyDto;
import com.exception.SssBadRequestException;
import com.cosium.spring.data.jpa.entity.graph.domain.EntityGraphs;

@Service
public class CompanyServiceImpl implements CompanyService {

    //@Autowired    Removed @Autowired for initiation during unit testing
    private final CompanyEntityRepo companyRepo;
    //@Autowired    Removed @Autowired for initiation during unit testing
    private final CompanyUserEntityRepo companyUserRepo;

    @Autowired
    public CompanyServiceImpl(CompanyEntityRepo companyRepo, CompanyUserEntityRepo companyUserRepo) {
        this.companyRepo = companyRepo;
        this.companyUserRepo = companyUserRepo;
    }

    // Gets a list off all business units this user has access to in a structured format.
    // The root of the object tree is the list will be the highest level the user has access to.
    @Override
    public List<CompanyDto> getCompaniesAssignedToUser(Integer userId) throws Exception {

        List<CompanyDto> response = new ArrayList<CompanyDto>();

        if( userId > 0 ) {
            UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
            userEntity.setId(userId);
            List<CompanyUserEntity> assignedCompanies = companyUserRepo.findByUserEntity(
                    userEntity, 
                    EntityGraphs.named("business-unit-user-entity-graph-BUSINESS-UNIT"));
            if( assignedCompanies != null && assignedCompanies.size() > 0 ) {
                for(CompanyUserEntity buEntity: assignedCompanies) {
                    CompanyDto company = new CompanyDto();
                    company.setId(buEntity.getCompanyEntity().getId());
                    company.setName(buEntity.getCompanyEntity().getName());
                    company.setSubUnits(getSubCompanies(buEntity.getCompanyEntity().getId()));

                    response.add(company);
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new SssBadRequestException("Request checking: invalid user id " + userId);
        }

        return response;
    }

    // Get sub business unit tree for a business unit
    // Method is called recursively to obtain all sub units of every unit in the tree.
    @Override
    public List<CompanyDto> getSubComapnies(Integer parentId) throws Exception {

        List<CompanyDto> response = null;

        if( parentId > 0 ) {
            CompanyEntity parentEntity = new CompanyEntity();
            parentEntity.setId(parentId);
            List<CompanyEntity> companies = companyRepo.findByParentCompanyEntity(parentEntity, null);
            if( companies != null && companies.size() > 0 ) {
                response = new ArrayList<CompanyDto>();

                for(CompanyEntity buEntity: companies) {
                    CompanyDto bu = new CompanyDto();
                    bu.setId(buEntity.getId());
                    bu.setName(buEntity.getName());
                    // Recursive iteration
                    List<CompanyDto> subList = getSubCompanies(bu.getId());
                    if(subList != null && subList.size() > 0) {
                        bu.setSubUnits(subList);
                    }

                    response.add(bu);
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new SssBadRequestException("Request checking: invalid business unit parent id " + parentId);
        }

        return response;
    }



}
```

### EDIT : Issue resolved

I have changed the implementation of the repository methods from entity params like below

`companyRepo.findByParentCompanyEntity(bu1, null);`

to simple pararameters like below

`companyRepo.findByParentCompanyID(int parentId);`

I was able to see Mockito method invocations after this - so this issue is resolved

Comment: You test is quite hard to read, you should really improve the `readability`. To create Lists with multiple entries use [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-). Also you should really add some `Builder` for your `DTO`'s, even if you just use them to create your Test Objects. You also should spell `company` correctly.

Comment: Also is `getSubComapnies` the same as `getSubComapnys`? The comment mentions this method is supposed to be recursive at least.

Comment: @second I have refactored the code and fixed these. For anonymising the code, I had replaced the real keyword with "Company" which was not done uniformly.

Comment: You're method names are still different `getSubComapnies` vs `getSubCompanies`.

Comment: You say that there are no invocations on `companyRepo`, which implies that the method is never called to begin with. Did you check (by debugging) what `companyUserRepo.findByUserEntity` actually returns? Might be that your mock is not matching.

Comment: @second This issue is solved now as per my edit. The issue might have been something to do with the objects that I was passing as parameters to the mock method were not identical to the objects which were actually passed

Comment: If thats what the issue was, you might have not implemented the proper `hashCode` and `equals` methods in the `CompanyEntity`.